# Error al ejecutar codigo de procedimiento almacenado para registrar datos en mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_registraVenta(
    INOUT cod int,
    cli varchar(150)
)
BEGIN
SET cod =(SELECT IFNULL(MAX(Cod_venta),0)+1 into cod FROM venta);
INSERT TO venta VALUES (cod, cli, CURDATE());
END;
```

Buen dia he tenido problemas con este codigo ya que al ejecutar me genera este error:

> MySQL ha dicho: Documentación
>
> ## 1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'into cod FROM venta)' en la linea 6

de ante mano muchas gracias por su apoyo. !

Comment: Intenta reemplazando en el `SELECT` anidado `into` por `AS`, es decir, `SELECT IFNULL(MAX(Cod_venta),0)+1 AS cod FROM venta`. Y en el `INSET`, el `TO` por `INTO`, es decir, `INSERT INTO venta VALUES (cod, cli, CURDATE());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontre el error y era de sintaxis asi que el codigo funcionando es:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_registrarVenta(
    INOUT cod int,
    cli varchar(150)
)
BEGIN
set cod =(SELECT IFNULL(MAX(Cod_venta),0)+1 FROM venta);
INSERT INTO venta VALUES (cod, cli, CURDATE());
END//
DELIMITER ;
```